# how to use json with jersey client to .net REST svc with weblogic?

Tags: java, .net, json, weblogic, jersey

My local tech stack is wl 9.2, jersey 1.1.5.1.

The remote REST svc is in ASP.net, and the response in the request body is described in a document as

```
{
    "Context" : 
    {
        "ID" : "0c351860a82d",        
        "Action" : "SomeAction",        
        "MessageID" : "5d220b792d7f",        
        "UriString" : "",        
        "ReferenceID" : "3ee8c695ffa5",        
        "Time" : "2009-02-11T01:37:44.52",        
        "ControlNbr" : "1.001"
    },    
    "Answer" : 
    {
        "Code" : 0,        
        "Detail" : ""
    },    
    "Exceptions" : [{
            "Code": 1,
            "Text": "Missing value ",
            "Trace": "trace from error.."
        },{
            "Code": 2,
            "Text": "Invalid input ",
            "Trace": "trace from error.."
        } ],   
    "Salt" : "196ac409",    
    "TmpKey" : "3ee8c695ffa5"
}
```

I've tried and mapped the above to POJOs that start like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SvcResponseBean {

    public SvcResponseBean() {}

    @XmlElement(name="Context")
    public ContextBean ctx;

    @XmlElement(name="Answer")
    public AnswerBean answ;

    @XmlElement(name = "Exceptions")
    public List<ExceptionBean> exs = new ArrayList<ExceptionBean>();

    @XmlElement(name="Salt")
    public String salt;

    @XmlElement(name="TmpKey")
    public String tmpKey;

    public void add(ExceptionBean eb) {exs.add(eb);}
}
```

The owners of the svc can help me only so much and not much with Jersey.
At runtime, the call

```
ClientResponse myClientResponse= myWebResourceBuilder.get(ClientResponse.class);
SvcResponseBeanpsrb = myClientResponse.getEntity(SvcResponseBean.class);
```

croaks with

```
java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.zzScanError(JsonLexer.java:468)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.yylex(JsonLexer.java:713)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.nextToken(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:153)
```

Obviously, I'm not that well versed in JSON and Jersey, but I'm learning.
Is there a way to make Jersey/JsonLexer tell me what exactly went wrong?
I know there are a number of different types of JSON formats out there, so perhaps that's my problem?

Any hints would be appreciated.

karoy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a copy-and-paste error, but the following is not valid JSON:

```
"Exceptions" : {
    "Code": 1,
    "Text": "Missing value ",
    "Trace": "trace from error.."
},{
    "Code": 2,
    "Text": "Invalid input ",
    "Trace": "trace from error.."
}    
"Salt" : "196ac409"
```

There is no key associated with the value `{ "Code": 2, "Text", ...` and there is nothing separating the `}` and `"Salt"`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for catching it. Copied the exception definition wrong from another part of the doc.

Comment: There's one thing I've come to realize: the .net REST server's response has the BOM, or Byte Order Marker, prepended in front of the JSON body.